# Max refresh rate for external monitor becomes unavailable

Tags: 22.04, display, external-monitor

I have my InfinityBook Pro 14 Gen 6 running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The latptop is connected to my external monitor (BenQ PD3220U) through the USB-C Thunderbolt port.

The maximum resolution supported by my monitor is 3840x2160 at 60Hz.

The problem I have is: most of the times I restart my laptop, the Max Refresh Rate available is 30Hz. Sometimes I restart the laptop and the 60Hz refresh rate is available for the max resolution but, most of the times, the refresh rate available is 30hz.

Does anybody know what I can do to always have my laptop working with the 60Hz refresh rate?

PS: yes, I checked the other questions and none of them seems to work for my problem.